# Brightcove Smart Player - Multiple Videos as Playlist

Tags: brightcove

I am upgrading my flash-only code to support the Brightcove Smart Player so it auto switch between HTML5.

I have been able to get the single video player switched over without problem. In the existing code, I can simulate a playlist by loading multiple videoIDs in javascript. My users do not create playlists in Brightcove. They can enter the videoIDs in our CMS and I load them dynamically.

Here is the old code:

```
function onTemplateReady(e) {
    videoList = exp.getElementByID("videoList");
    if (videoList != null) {
        var mediaIdsToRequest = videoIDs;
        content.getMediaInGroupAsynch(mediaIdsToRequest);
    }
    videoLoading = false;

}

function onMediaCollectionLoad(e) {

    if (e.mediaCollection != null) { // This means the mediaCollection is a Playlist or group of videos
        var mediaDTOs = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < e.mediaCollection.mediaCount; i++) {
            mediaDTOs[i] = content.getMedia(e.mediaCollection.mediaIds[i]);
        }
        videoList.setData(mediaDTOs);

        // Visually selects the first video in the list
        videoList.setSelectedIndex(0);

        // Cues up the first video of the list in the videoPlayer component but doesn't start playing it
        video.cueVideo(mediaDTOs[0].id);
    }

}
```

We basically include a parameter called videoList that is a comma separated list of videoIDs. The problem seems to be that the MEDIA_COLLECTION_LOAD event is not in the new API. What is the recommend way to do this now?

Comment: Looks like the VideoPlayer class might be handling this now.  Check out this smart player solution: http://support.brightcove.com/en/docs/dynamically-loading-videos-using-smart-player-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is not supported in the new Smart Player API per Brightcove Support. You can build your own playlists in HTML now however, you cannot feed individual videos into an existing playlist player.